# Rules for field names in ElasticSearch 6?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Currently all what I can find online is:

- must not start with underscore "_"
- must not contain comma ","
- must not contain hash mark "#"
- usage of point "." is discouraged but possible
- field names must not be longer than 255

But it seems that these are the rules for ElasticSearch 5 and older versions.

I did some experiments and found:

- using dots (`.`) may result in various kinds of errors, e.g. `illegal_state_exception`, `array_index_out_of_bounds_exception`, but sometimes it's legal
- empty strings are not allowed (`illegal_argument_exception`)
- leading underscores, commas, hash marks seem to be legal in ElasticSearch 6
- field names can be longer than 255 (but perhaps there's a new limit?)

I wonder whether there's an official document for this? Am I just being blind?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently planning an upgrade from 5.6.5 to 6.2.x.

I'm looking for evidence to support the worrying comment "...as **underscores in field names will not be allowed**" mentioned in [Breaking Changes for Watcher in 6.0.0-alpha2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/xes-6.0.0-alpha2.html#xes-breaking-6.0.0-alpha2).

I've been unable to find any additional evidence that underscores are now verboten.  I'll open a support case referencing this question to get an official response on this.

Comment: I'm using ES 6.2.2 and using underscores is totally fine. Either the document is somewhat wrong or the change's been reverted in newer versions, I guess... Could you please provide the link to your support case, or if it's an email thread, loop me in?

Comment: Elastic support has confirmed that only leading underscores are reserved for internal use.  Underscores elsewhere in field names are fully supported.